# QGIS OpenCL settings fall back to onboard-graphics

Tags: qgis, mac, opencl, gpu

I am running QGIS 3.4.14 on my Mac 16', with a Radeon 5500 GPU. 
I've enabled the OpenCL support in QGIS settings as well as my user profile settings.

It offers me the CPU, the built-in oonboard GPU Nvidia 630 as well as the Radeon 5500.
[image: Radeon Selection in OpenCL]
Unfortunately, when selecting the Radeon and shutting QGIS down and start it again it always selects the NVIDIA and not the more powerful Radeon.

Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing a similar behaviour with QGIS 3.22.1.
However in `~/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis.org/QGIS3.ini` OpenCL setting persists app restart and won't change until one presses "OK" in Preferences window.

```
OpenClDefaultDevice=AMD Radeon Pro 5500M Compute Engine|AMD|OpenCL 1.2 |GPU
OpenClEnabled=true
```

So this may be an interface issue.